# Excel vba copy and paste cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I can see my code is working to copy the correct cells, but the final paste is incorrect.

Workbook 1 - w cells to copy ("C5:E287"), but the final result should paste in workbook 2 ("H11:J293") - but ends up pasting S9:S285 in the first column, V9:V285 in the second and W9:W285 in the third.

Not sure why and whether I have my cell references wrong

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ward As Worksheet
Dim Data As Worksheet

Set wB = Workbooks("a.xlsm")
Set w = wB.Sheets("DATA")

SourcePath = Workbooks("a.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("AB1").Text
SourceFile1 = Workbooks("a.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("AA1").Text
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath & SourceFile1 & ".xlsm")
Set Data = wb2.Sheets("DATA")

bIsEmpty = False

    If w.Range("C2") = "3" Then
    w.Range("C5:E287").Copy
    Data.Range("H11:J293").PasteSpecial
    ElseIf wB.ward.Range("C2") = "5" Then
    bIsEmpty = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Eh? I can't see any reference to `S9:S285`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use .copy and .PasteSpecial?

Assign range value...

```
Data.Range("H11:J293").Value =  w.Range("C5:E287").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

One can copy paste values also by reading to/writing from a variant array:

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim Destination As Range

'your code......

'reads values to dynamically sied variant array
Arr =  w.Range("C5:E287")  

'Sets left corner and size of range destination and fills it by Arr values.
Set Destination = Data.Range("H11")
Destination.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
```

It has an additional value for reading data to process that in VBa internal data structures and writing finals back to spreadsheets, what if often much faster.
More in the invaluable article [CPearson Arrays And Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)